# Narrow Line Break

Tags: html, css

Is there a more efficient way than

```
<div style="height: 6px;"></div>
```

To make a "narrow" line break? i.e. narrower than

```
text text text<br/><br/>
```

??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
margin-bottom : 6px;
```

on the element above the desired break.  So, like

```
<p style="margin-bottom : 6px;">
    text text text
</p>
```

Comment: I had to use spans with display: block applied as well

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to sort out the margin so go ahead and input:

```
margin-bottom:6px;

<p style="margin-bottom:6px;">
     Whatever text you want </p>
```

Best of luck!